# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED NextJS 14 app in docker

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose, deployment, dockerfile

I've several apps running with docker compose.
All the applications are accessible except my NextJS app is suddenly inaccessible after a new deployment.

If I sent a curl request to http://localhost:8100 I get:

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

If I sent a curl request to http://localhost:8082 I receive the actual page response.

It might be due to changes I've made to the nextjs app. However during development everything runs fine and the build also runs as expected.

The NextJS app seems to be deployed correctly, I at least get this output after starting the NextJS container:

```
> ▲ Next.js 14.1.0
> - Local: http://localhost:8100
> - Network: http://0.0.0.0:8100
> ✓ Ready in 219ms
```

docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:

  admin:
    image: 'registry.gitlab.com/...react-app:latest'
    container_name: admin
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 8082
    ports:
      - 8082:80
    networks:
      - app-network

  nextjs-app:
    image: 'registry.gitlab.com/...nextjs-14-app:latest'
    container_name: nextjs-app
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 8100
    ports:
      - 8100:80
    networks:
      - app-network
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

FROM base AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN npx prisma generate
RUN yarn build


FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs public

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 8100

ENV PORT 8100
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Comment: Can try `8100: 8100`  in the section of `nextjs-app`

Answer (score 1):

In your Docker Compose file, you have mapped the Next.js app's container port `80` to the host port `8100`:

```yaml
ports:
  - 8100:80
```

However, in your Dockerfile, you set `EXPOSE` and environment variables for port `8100`:

```
EXPOSE 8100

ENV PORT 8100
```

The internal port your application listens to should match the internal port specified in the Docker Compose `ports` mapping. If your Next.js app listens on port `8100`, the Docker Compose file should reflect it:

```yaml
ports:
  - 8100:8100
```